# jRuby Zip out of Memory

Tags: ruby, zip, jruby

We have a small utility that finds unused items on our server and zips them up then moves them this is written in jRuby. When we go to run this on the actual servers needing clean up they run out of memory before they can complete the operation of the clean up. The java memory is as high as we can get it to run stably on 32bit and we can't move to 64bit at this time it is around 1800m max heap size. There is our main application running as well that we would like to avoid shutting down. The zips the system is creating are 800megs plus is there any way to do this and not have the entire zip file open in memory?

Comment: What ZIP library are you using? Zip files can be created using constant-space memory.

Comment: Just the jruby 'zip/zip'

Comment: The rubyzip gem, perhaps, you are using? Yeah I'd suggest moving the file to some temp directory then running gzip against it or what not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you execute zip via the command line?

You may also want to look at pbzip2, you will still need tar to do the archival of multiple files though.